# Usage of BIPOLAR as an adjective in medical terminology

Tags: terminology, medical

I'm doing a research on medical terms and their usage in general language. I'm working on BIPOLAR which is kind of misused in laymen speech, e.g. "*I feel bipolar today*" which actually means "*I feel moody today*".

But what I'm mainly interested in is whether **in medical terminology** BIPOLAR exists as an adjective used to say someone has a bipolar disorder. Would it be appropriate (in medical terms!) to say something like "*This patient is bipolar*"? I'm only interested in predicate adjective. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *“Sometimes, it is not possible to determine whether the patient is bipolar on the first visit.”*


Personality Disorders and Panic Attacks Essential Concepts • 
Mental Health Service Evaluation - Pag.75

Comment: Google NGrams is a good fit for this

Comment: @Gio that's a very nice example, thank you

Comment: What do you mean, "misused"? https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bipolar

Comment: I would think that a person called bipolar would feel manic at one moment, and depressed at another, not just bipolar at any particular time. (Unless they are of two minds about it).